# How to use a single command to build a maven project and deploy it in tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, maven, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I am new to Java and Springsource tool suite.

Currently, I am running the following commands one after the other to deploy the project in tomcat.

- mvn clean package
- mvn tomcat:run

In SpringSource tool suite, I use `Run as -> maven Build` and first using the goal as `clean package`. Then I again use `Run as -> maven Build` with goal as `tomcat:run`.

Can these two command be done in a single execution?

I was told that Linux allows such a process as mvn clean package;mvn tomcat:run

Is there any way to replicate this in Windows?

Every time I try this in windows I get the message showing that the program has started a thread that cannot be stopped.

Comment: Can't you use mvn clean package tomcat:run?

Comment: Regarding the comment about linux, *nix `OS`es just allow you to specify a string of commands one after the other separated by semi-colon. So, it's not specific to maven on linux. Just to clarify.

Comment: @Vikdor: Windows supports the same thing (just uses a different separator)

Comment: oh! I didn't know that. Thanks (http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx?mfr=true)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As said before, you can invoke a Maven command with several actions on the same line.
Generally, you invoke Maven with some *phases* like in `mvn clean install site`.
The phases belong to a [lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) (Clean, Default or Site).

You can also add some *goals* invocations in addition to the *phases*. They will be  be executed in sequence.
Like in `mvn clean dependency:copy-dependencies package` ([Running Maven Tools](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html#Running_Maven_Tools)).

The execution time will be optimized if you execute all of your tasks in one command rather than with severals invocations.